# Vue.js : update Bottstrap progressBar within loop in Method

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding

My problem :

I have a Vue.js method directive who declare a loop from 1 to 1.000.000.  I would like to update my progressBar at 50%. So when i == 500000, I would like witdh css rules of my progressBar is 50%.

Here is the html code for the progressBar

```
 <div id="app">
 <button v-on:click.stop="executeLoop()">Execute the loop</button>

  <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" 
           v-bind:style="barWidthCalculated" v-bind:aria-valuenow="barWidthCalculated" 
           aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Vue.js code

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){ return {
        progression : 0,
    }},

    methods: {
        executeLoop: function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
                    if (i == 500000) {
                        this.progression = 50;                        
                        //this.$set(this, progression, 30); // This instruction gives me "Reference error: progression is not defined"
                    }
                }
        },
    },

    computed: {
        barWidthCalculated: function () {
            return {
                width: this.progression + '%'
            };
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: so what is your problem? if you are saying the error on `this.$set`, try this `this.$set(this.$data, 'progression', 30)`

Comment: a string or number variable does not require `this.$set` you only need that for objects and arrays, nevertheless, it's a good habit)

Comment: My problem is this display the update of the progression bar after the loop is ended. I would like to update the progressbar in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/183735/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .loader-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: gray;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .loader {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="loader-wrapper">
            <div class="loader" :style="{ width: widthPercentage }"></div>
            {{ widthPercentage }}
        </div>


        <button @click="start">Start</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",

            data: {
                width: 0
            },

            computed: {
                widthPercentage() {
                    return this.width + "%";
                }
            },

            methods: {
                start() {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
                        if (i === 500000) {
                            this.width = 50;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that this is very inefficient, because each click will trigger this massive loop. At this point it doesn't matter if you will loop 10 or 1000000 times, because it will still take 1  frame to render. The difference is that bigger loop will make this frame take longer to render.

Comment: I working on your answer. But It update the value of width only at the end of the loop. Is it ? I would like the progressBar width is dynamicaly modified so the user can see the progression. Tell me if I'm wrong please

Comment: @Mz1907 https://jsfiddle.net/mnogk5xr/ - simply change value of "delay" to make loader move faster or slower.